# What are eigenvalues and eigenvectors really?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know how to determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a given matrix $A$, but we were not really explained to what exactly ARE eigenvalues and eigenvectors, what is their purpose and what exactly do/can they tell us about a matrix/system?

Can someone please provide me with some information about this? It will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/23312/215011

Comment: @grand_chat - Thank you so much! :). That really is an AMAZING explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, the nonzero $n$-component column vector $x$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$ if $A x = \lambda x$.

See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) which discusses many of the uses of these.