# Usage of Eigenvalue and Eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been working with factor and cluster analysis where I found the introduction of Eigenvalue. So, I read about it and I have understood the idea how to find it but still, I am unable to see the application or the meaning(in layman's term) of it. if I will teach this to someone than what should I say? is it the direction of the vector or the transformation of a matrix into vector form. I have read that google search engine use it to show the predicted words. I am not getting how do they do it?

Can somebody please help me into this.

Comment: An eigenvector is a vector which stays pointing in the same direction after you apply a linear map (i.e. a matrix) to it. The corresponding eigenvalue is how much this vector stretches / squashes under this transformation.

Comment: I have been asking if there is any real life application of this. As I have read about Google search engine, but how I do not understand that, can you please explain me that.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed many times. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23325/229471) and of course [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors).

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer (but I get that you can't yet comment). Unfortunately I already voted to close this as unclear, so won't be able to close as a duplicate. Hopefully someone that sees this can vote to close as a duplicate

Comment: I would have commented if i could. Interestingly, it seems i can comment my own post, though. I wasn't able to close as duplicate either..

Comment: Yep you can comment on any of you own questions or answers no matter what rep you have. I think the threshold for closing questions is 3000 rep.