# Why did someone come up with the formula $\mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{AP}=\mathbf{D}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> For Diagonalizable matrix
>
> I wonder why/how someone came up with the formula:
>
> $$\mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{AP}=\mathbf{D}$$
>
> and not something else like following:
>
> $$\mathbf{AP}=\mathbf{D} $$
>
> $$\text{or}$$
>
> $$\mathbf{PA}=\mathbf{D}$$

Comment: Can you give some more context? What is P, D and A?

Comment: @sdsad: do you mean intuition behind diagonalization?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR yeah i think that's what he's asking

Comment: That is correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let ${X_1}, {X_2} \cdots {X_n} $ be independent Eigen vectors of a square matrix A corresponding to the Eigen values $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots , \lambda_n$.

Let $P = [{X_1} \  {X_2} \cdots {X_n}]$ be the matrix with columns containing Eigen vectors.

Also we have, $$A{X_i} = \lambda_i{X_i}$$

So, $$AP  = [A{X_1} \  A{X_2} \cdots A{X_n}] = [\lambda_1{X_1} \  \lambda_2{X_2} \cdots \lambda_n{X_n}]$$

$$AP = [{X_1} \  {X_2} \cdots {X_n}]\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\0 &\lambda_2 &\cdots & 0
\\ \vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots &\lambda_n \end{bmatrix} $$

$$AP = PD$$

where $D$ is the diagonal matrix. $P$ is invertible as the Eigen vectors are independent and $|P| \not= 0$.

So,

> $$P^{-1}AP = D$$

We can compute the higher indices of $A$ from the above equation.

$$D^2 = P^{-1}A^2P$$

$$D^3 = P^{-1}A^3P$$

$$\vdots$$

$$D^k = P^{-1}A^kP$$

or

> $$A^k = PD^kP^{-1}$$

So, it is conventional to write it as $P^{-1}AP = D$

Comment: Thanks. But still, why would you think about eigenvectors in the first place?

Comment: Are you asking about the isolation in $$AP = [{X_1} \  {X_2} \cdots {X_n}]\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\0 &\lambda_2 &\cdots & 0
\\ \vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots &\lambda_n \end{bmatrix}$$ ?

Comment: Not really. You derive the formula by using eigenvectors. But why do you even think about eigenvectors and not anything else? My question is more about the intuition for how someone ended up with this formula - like why did they think about eigenvectors and not any other construct

Comment: Possibly worth reading: [What is the importance of eigenvalues/eigenvectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23312/what-is-the-importance-of-eigenvalues-eigenvectors)

Answer (score 1):

For a linear transformation $A$ on a vector space (finite) $U$, we know that $A$ can be `represented' by a matrix. We usually denote this matrix by $[A]_{\mathcal{B}}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $U$.

Taking the basis for $U$ consisting of eigenvectors of  $A$ (when this is  possible, i.e. when $A$ has $dim(U)$ linearly independent eigenvectors), gives a particularly simple (diagonal) $[A]_{\mathcal{B}}$ (this is your $D$).

Answer (score 1):

The defining equation for eigenvectors is $A\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$. If we have a bunch of eigenvectors $\mathbf v_i$ with associated eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, using basic properties of matrix multiplication we can collect up all of the individual equations into a single “bulk” equation $$A\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v_1 & \cdots & \mathbf v_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf v_1 & \mathbf v_2 & \cdots & \mathbf v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0&\lambda_2&\cdots&0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0&0&\cdots&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix},$$ or $AP=PD$ for short. Note that the matrix of eigenvalues *right*-multiplies the eigenvector matrix: we want to multiply each *column* of $P$ by the appropriate value.

If $A$ is diagonalizable, we can choose eigenvectors $\mathbf v_n$ such that they form a basis for the space, in which case $P$ will be square and invertible, so we can multiply both sides by $P^{-1}$ to get $P^{-1}AP=D$. I often use the equation $AP=PD$ as a starting point because I can never remember which side the inverse matrix goes on and it’s easy to derive from the fundamental eigenvector equation.

Comment: An easy way to remember is by noting that $D $ operates on coordinate vectors with respect to basis of eigenvectors. So on the LHS of the matrix equation we need a vector expressed as coordinate vector wrt basis consisting of eigenvectirs  The columns of this transition matrix  are the eigenvectors as coordinate vectors wrt to the standard basis. Hence we apply $P $ to get a vector wrt standard basis, so that $A $ can be applied to it (if $A $ is standard matrix representation of our linear transfirmation).

Comment: @AnyAD As Señor Wences used to say, “Easy for you; hard for me.” $A\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$ is ingrained in stone. The rest is an almost trivial symbolic manipulation. For other things, remembering “input” and “output” bases is indeed easy.

Comment: Don't disagree. (Thinking about transition matrices is sometimes useful, obviously depending on what one is trying to highlight)