# Solving the differential equations as shown below

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I recently came across a question in which we had to to solve the set of differential equations:

> $10dx/dt+x+y/2=0 $ and $6d(x-y)/dt= y$

I tried a lot to solve these equations but I was unable to do so. I tried adding them eliminating  $t$, but I couldn't even solve the resulting differential equation. Substituting $y=mx$ resulted in a messy calculation. Would someone please help me to solve this question?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23325). You need an apropriate linear variable change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

This is a linear system of differential equations. Rewrite it in standard form:
\begin{cases}
x'= -\dfrac 1{10}x-\dfrac 1{20}y \\[1ex]
y'=-\dfrac 1{10}x -\dfrac{13}{60}y
\end{cases}
(subtracting the 2nd equation from the 1st), which you can write in matrix form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}, \qquad A=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac 1{10}-\frac 1{20}\\-\frac 1{10}-\frac{13}{60}\end{bmatrix}$$
The solution is given by
$$\begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\ y(t)\end{bmatrix}=\exp(At)\begin{bmatrix}x(0)\\ y(0)\end{bmatrix}$$
so all you have to do is calculating the exponential of $At$, which requires to determine a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you very much